# Wavefile.read gives File format b'\x00\x00\x00\x1c'... not understood

Tags: python, scipy, wav

I'm trying to read a wave file in python

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
fname = "good.wav"
sample_rate, samples = wavfile.read(fname)
```

However I get the following error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ae3602287699> in <module>
      3 from scipy.io import wavfile
      4 
----> 5 sample_rate, samples = wavfile.read(fname)
      6 frequencies, times, spectrogram = signal.spectrogram(samples, sample_rate)
      7 

in read(filename, mmap)
    234 
    235     try:
--> 236         file_size, is_big_endian = _read_riff_chunk(fid)
    237         fmt_chunk_received = False
    238         channels = 1

 in _read_riff_chunk(fid)
    166         # There are also .wav files with "FFIR" or "XFIR" signatures?
    167         raise ValueError("File format {}... not "
--> 168                          "understood.".format(repr(str1)))
    169 
    170     # Size of entire file

ValueError: File format b'\x00\x00\x00\x1c'... not understood.
```

Guess I need to convert my file first somehow in a different wave file as it plays correctly. Anybody a hint how to do this ideally on a Mac.

Comment: Where is `fname` defined?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Somewhere else in the Jupiter notebook just thought fname="good.wav" ist not really improving the question

Comment: it was incase your string was being interpreted as a file object

Comment: Apparently your file is not actually a WAV file.  Where did you get it?  How was it created?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I got them externally and have no clue how they were created. According to iTunes it is a wav audio file / 1.152 kbps /24 bit / 48 kHz

Comment: Ah, 24 bit... SciPy's WAV reader can't read 24 bit files.  That's not the error that I expect to see, though.  Which version of SciPy are you using? You can check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`.  A relatively recent version of SciPy got a nicer error message for this case.

Comment: Version is 1.3.1. Which format is suggested?

Comment: @CAFEBABE. Were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same issue now. scipy version 1.4.1.

Comment: @Anshul sadly no

Comment: @CAFEBABE [after 2 years] Were you able to solve it?

Comment: sadly haven't been able to solve it